# Rust doc test with async function #[tokio-test]

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio

It seems one cannot use `#[tokio-test]` for test async functions in the Rust doc test?

For now I have to write an async main function and tag it with `#[tokio-main]` and call `test_fn().await` in it to let some async function run during `cargo test --doc`.

Is there some other better ways to allow doc tests run as if it is a normal test function, for example with `#[tokio-test]`? Also it would be nice if the tag `#[tokio-test]` can be shown in the doc, so users can copy the doc and use it as a test directly in their project. (And this probably can be done like `##[tokio-test]`?)

Answer (score 9):

Doc tests automatically wrap the code block in a *synchronous* `fn main() { ... }`. `.await`ing requires an *asynchronous* runtime. You cannot `.await` without spawning some sort of runtime. You *could* spawn a regular, multi-threaded runtime for each doc test:

````rust
/// ```rust
/// #[tokio::main]
/// async fn main() {
///    let len = async { "aaaa".len() }.await;
///    assert_eq!(len, 4);
/// }
/// ```
````

..but that's probably not the best idea. A better way would be to use [`tokio_test::block_on`](https://docs.rs/tokio-test/0.4.2/tokio_test/fn.block_on.html) which uses a test local runtime (similar to `#[tokio::test]`) to block on the provided future:

````rust
/// ```rust
/// # tokio_test::block_on(async {
/// let len = async { "aaaa".len() }.await;
/// assert_eq!(len, 4);
/// # })
/// ```
````

Comment: Thank you. The issue I have is that I would like to use doc to show how to write async code tests with `#[tokio-test]`. But if `#[tokio-test]` cannot be used with doc, then I might not able to write a doc that can show how to use `#[tokio-test]` and also make the doc's code run during cargo test.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use asynchronous code in doctests without spawning a new runtime for each you can just wrap the whole doctest instead of just the async part in a [`tokio_test::block_on`](https://docs.rs/tokio-test/0.3.0/tokio_test/fn.block_on.html).

Example:

````rust
/// Asynchronously get length of "aaaa"
/// ```
/// # tokio_test::block_on(async {
///   let len = async { "aaaa".len() };
///   assert_eq!(len.await, 4)
/// # })
/// ```
````

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be a good solutioon.

Comment: Note that in the current (0.4.2) version of `tokio_test::block_on()`, this will create a new runtime, so it's roughly equivalent to `# tokio::runtime::Handle::new().unwrap().block_on(async {`

Answer (score -1):

I do not know enough about your special use case but maybe you want to avoid the async runtime and wrap your documentation code block like this:

````
/// ...
/// Example
/// ```rust,no_run // <- try using this `no_run` tag
/// ...
/// #[tokio::main]
/// async fn main() {
/// ...
/// }
/// ...
/// ```
````